# Angular Datepicker with 2 differents dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I try to make this script work with 2 different dates :

http://fiddle.jshell.net/yXjkq/1/

It is working with the first one but not the second one. And I am trying to understand why?

JavaScript:

```
var mySecondModule = angular.module('MyReportModule', []);

function TheReportCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selectedDate = "Aladdin";
    $scope.selectedDate2 = "Aladdin2";
}
mySecondModule.directive('datepicker', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //using $parse instead of scope[attrs.datepicker] for cases
            //where attrs.datepicker is 'foo.bar.lol'
            parsed = $parse(attrs.datepicker);
            $(element).datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        parsed.assign(scope, dateText);
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyReportModule">
  <div ng-controller="TheReportCtrl">

   <input type="text" datepicker="selectedDate" />{{selectedDate}} 
   <input type="text" datepicker="selectedDate2" />{{selectedDate2}} 

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing this `parsed = $parse(attrs.datepicker);` to `var parsed = $parse(attrs.datepicker);` worked for me. Please try and let us know.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this at work tomorrow and let you know, but looks like it should be this. ;)

Comment: Yes working! Thank you Rajkamal for spotting this, have a good day!